# My Xcode is connect to BitBucket. Now when do I fork, branch, and commit?

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

I've connected my Xcode project from my iMac to a private repo on BitBucket so that I can share my project between my iMac and Macbook Pro.

Now what?

When I go to my MacBook and connect to the repo and check out the project, what do I do when I want to go back to the iMac?  Commit the changes?  Then do I have to checkout the whole thing from the repo again on my iMac?

I've only ever used version control locally and by myself.  What's the actual process for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my final solution using the answers/comments above:

1. Create the repository in Bitbucket and get the repository server address.
2. Open the working project in Xcode on the iMac and add the Bitbucket repository as a Remote repository.
3. Use the Source Control | Push command to push the current, local commits to the Bitbucket repository.
4. On the MacBook computer, check out the project from the remote repository.
5. After making changes on the MacBook, commit them and choose the option at the bottom of the commit window to push the changes to the remote.
6. Go back to the iMac and use the Source Control | Pull command to get the changes from the repository and merge them back into the working copy on the iMac.

From what I read in the other answers there is lots to learn about workflow with git, but for now, this will work for me.

Further, this link also helped me understand the pushes/pulls/commits, etc. as they pertain to git.  http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/21/pushing-and-pulling.html

Answer (score 0):

You have cloned the bitbucket repository on both the MacBook and iMac. To communicate the changes between the two you'll have to commit a change and push it to bitbucket (on the iMac say), and then pull or fetch/rebase on the other (ie MacBook) - it's the standard flow with git.

This is a good reference: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows, just think of yourself as two different developers, on your two different boxes.

Comment: That document is nice and clear about workflow in general.  Good info.  It's the rebasing one of the copies, specifically in Xcode, that I am confused about.